# Which points are localised in which WMS layer?

Tags: qgis, wms

I have several different layers in WMS format and individual points/locations. The goal is to find out which points are in which WMS layers. Unfortunately, I have not been working with QGIS for long and am at a loss. Can anyone please help me or is there already a forum post with the solution to my problem?

[image]

This is a simplified example image of my problem.
The red circle is a WMS layer. I want QGIS to tell me which of the yellow points are in the circle.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: turn the layers on/off one at a time to see which points disappear?

Comment: There are about 50 different WMS layers and thousands of points to be examined. The goal is to generate an overview that assigns all points to be examined to the respective WMS layers. Switching layers on and off manually would be far too time-consuming. That's why I'm hoping for an automated solution/function in QGIS. 

It is difficult to say where I am stuck, as I simply lack the approach to solve this problem. I have tried a few things in the vector/rat analysis tools. Nothing has worked.

I also tried to convert the WMS layers into a polygon layer. Unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'll try to describe my problem as best I can: I have about 50 different layers (WMS format) that represent surfaces. I also have a vector with a number of locations (individual points). I want to use QGIS to create an overview that shows me which locations (points) are in which layers. 

I would like to use a function like "extract by position". Instead of polygons I have WMS layers.

Comment: I have tried to use the tools under vector selection, vector analysis, raster analysis. I have also tried to convert the WMS layers into polygons. That did not work either.
In the function "extract by position" I cannot select the WMS layers in the selection field "by comparing to the features from". They are not even suggested to me.

I wonder now if I need to convert the WMS layers into another format or if I just can't find the needed function in QGIS.

Comment: A wms layer will cover the entire map, so this doesn't make sense

Comment: does that mean there is no solution to my problem?

Comment: I think it means you haven't explained your problem well enough for us to understand - may be a picture would help?

Comment: The red circle can't represent the WMS layer, the WMS layer would be the whole image. (a WMS layer cannot be a circle).   A WMS doesn't give you any features, it gives you an image that shows you where the features exist - the red circle

Comment: If you know where the points exist (pixel coordinates in the WMS image/canvas), you could do a series of GetFeatureInfo requests for all layers and work out which gave you any result

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: This means that not only the red circle but the entire image is the WMS, right? 
Unfortunately, I only get the WMS data in this format. Is it possible in QGIS to recognise areas by their colour differences?

If the WMS and the points have the same coordinate system, then the coordinates of the points should match the WMS, right? 
What is the best way to make such a query in QGIS? I don't have any information about what the red circle is or what the white area around it is.

Comment: I found this website: https://geoconverter.infs.ch/wms 
Is it possible with this? Which format should I choose?

Comment: Yes the WMS layer is the whole image, the red circle and the white/colourless surrounding area.  For a GetFeatureInfo request you need the pixel coordinates of the points, not the real world coordinates, the WMS layers and the points having the same CRS is not important.